# how to write a left join for make loop

Tags: php, mysql

I want to write this code in one query with `left join` statement. Currently I use php for loop this query but its not  good and is too slow

It's app that have `like` and `dislike` option. I want number of every user's like

```
     public function getUserLikedCount($id) {
        $query = $this->db->query(
          "SELECT * FROM `users`, post, `like`
            WHERE users.id = post.post_user_id
            AND like.like_post_id = post.post_id
            AND users.id = ?
            AND post.post_is_active = 1", array($id)
        );
        return $query->num_rows();
    }
```

thanks

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: @Strawberry I want to write whole of this in one query more detailes in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44735985/sql-sub-queries-calculate-score/44736037#44736037)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like it ( I don't know your table `like` structure):

```
$sql = 'SELECT u.id AS `user_id`
               COUNT(p.post_id) AS `liked_cnt` <-- or like.id ( if this field exists)
        FROM `post` AS p
        LEFT JOIN `users` AS u
          ON ( u.id = p.post_user_id )
        LEFT JOIN `like` AS l
          ON ( l.like_post_id = p.post_id )  
        WHERE  p.post_is_active = 1
              AND l.status = 1 <-- "liked"
        GROUP BY u.id ';
```

Comment: Note that `LEFT JOIN x... WHERE x =...` is the same as `INNER JOIN x...`

Comment: @Strawberry Hmmm... Are you sure in your assertion? I emphraze attention on "the same".

Comment: no , I want to remove `user.id = ?` from query. and query return all users post likes. something like this `SELECT u.id , COUNT(l.id) FROM ...`

Comment: @voodoo417 Of course. You can always execute EXPLAIN EXTENDED followed by SHOW WARNINGS on such a query, in case there's any uncertainty

Comment: @Strawberry Sorry, how does EXPLAIN EXTENDED relate with your assertion that "`LEFT JOIN x... WHERE x =...` is the same as `INNER JOIN x...`" ?..

Comment: Suck it and see

Comment: @Masoud Tavakkoli Sorry, I`m not understanding what you want to achieve now... What is the problem? Modify that query.

Comment: dear @voodoo417 please check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44735985/sql-sub-queries-calculate-score) to see every thing. thanks for your help

Comment: @Strawberry Sorry, in all cases? I don't agree with u. I imagine situations/conditions where will not be possible just using `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` + `WHERE`. Just think.

Comment: @Masoud Tavakkoli Ok. Group by `user_id`. Have updated answer. IMHO, you need to learn SQL more...

Comment: @voodoo417 thanks very much  I'm a newbe in SQL,can you help me a little more to solve whole of this problem in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44735985/sql-sub-queries-calculate-score)

Comment: @Strawberry I want to say that your assertion "Note that LEFT JOIN x... WHERE x =... is the same as INNER JOIN x..." it's not correct. I'm sure.

Comment: @Masoud Tavakkoli Sorry.. I have to go. Sunday). P.S. I have looked that thread. Think, before you need to figure out issues with `JOINS` and how they work...

Comment: @voodoo417 Ok, Thanks for your help

Comment: Well now you know how to test your assertion against mine, I'll leave it up to you to decide whether or not you wish to do so.

Comment: @Strawberry Sorry, look - I know exactly about `EXPLAIN` and `EXPLAIND EXTENDED`. And use it. I'm saing about your assertion that "Note that LEFT JOIN x... WHERE x =... is the same as INNER JOIN x...". I 'm reapting again my queastion above "In all cases?". Forget about current situation. Imagine more difficult case and selection - using "INNER JOIN" istead of "LEFT JOIN + WHERE" will be impossible. Therefore I can`t say like you that "INNER JOIN is the same like LEFT JOIN + WHERE".  "I'll leave it up to you to decide whether or not you wish to do so" - ok, we agreed). Have a nice day!)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this :  
  $query = $this->db->query(
              "SELECT * FROM `users` u
            LEFT  JOIN post p ON u.id = p.post_user_id AND u.id =?        
            LEFT  JOIN like l ON l.like_post_id = p.post_id AND p.post_is_active = 1
             ", array($id)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit] your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.